# AJAX login form reloading the page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Trying to create a login form using AJAX so the page does not have to change to log a user in. So far I have the following after using a tutorial I found however I have the problem of the form is reloading the page instead of calling the JavaScript function.

HTML:

```
<form class="login-form" onSubmit="check_login();return false;">
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email">
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
    <button type="submit" class="btn trans login-button">Login</button>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
// Retrieve login values from POST variables
$email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
$password = strip_tags($_POST['password']);

// Salt and hash password for database comparison
$password = saltHash($password);

// Check that both fields are not empty
if(!empty($email) || !empty($password)) {

// Query database to check email and password match entry
$database->query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email AND password = :password');
$database->bind(':email',$email);
$database->bind(':password',$password);
$result = $database->single();

if(!empty($result)) {

    // Check entered details match the database
    if($email == $result['email'] && $password == $result['password']) {
        // If login details are correct, return 1
        echo '1';
    }

}
else {
    // If not returned results, return 2
    echo '2';
}

}
else {
    // If either fields are empty, return 3
    echo '3';
}
```

JavaScript / jQuery:

```
// Login function
function check_login() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'check-login.php',
        data: 'email=' + $('input[value="email"]').val() + '&password=' + $('input[value="password"]').val(),
        success: function(response){
            if(response === '1') {
                alert('Log In Success');
            }
            else if(response === '2') {
                alert('Incorrect Details');
            }
            else if(response === '3') {
                alert('Fill In All Fields');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you try to `alert` before the ajax? just to check if it is working or not? Something likee `function check_login(){ alert('hi') }`

Comment: It fires the form submit as soon as the button is pressed.

Comment: @stu177 Try removing `return false;` - `return` will stop execution from thereon.

Comment: @stu177 And is `saltHash` a built-in function? Never seen that before. You probably meant `$password = hash($password);` ?

Comment: try only "return false" on submit i.e. onSubmit="return false;" and call the function check_login(); on click of the button.

Also, on php(server site) try using exit; after you echo. If still facing problem then please let me know. dineshs@mindfiresolutions.com

Answer (score 1):

Use This bro...

```
<form id="F_login" class="login-form">
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email">
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
    <button id="btn_login" type="submit" class="btn trans login-button">Login</button>
</form>

$("#btn_login").click(function(){
    var parm = $("#F_login").serializeArray();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'check-login.php',
        data: parm,
        success: function (response) {              
            if(response === '1') {
                alert('Log In Success');
            }
            else if(response === '2') {
                alert('Incorrect Details');
            }
            else if(response === '3') {
                alert('Fill In All Fields');
            }

        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert("Login Fail...");
        }
    });
});
            else if(response === '3') {
                alert('Fill In All Fields');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

It should run well...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<form class="login-form">
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email">
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
    <button class="btn trans login-button" onclick="check_login()">Login</button>
</form>
```

When the login submits, it will still try to reload the page, so you should remove the submit type and put the login function on the button

Comment: Page still refreshing with default GET headers set.

Answer (score 0):

Attaching event listeners via tags is not a good practice and using jQuery for it it's cleaner and easier.

Try doing this:

```
$("form.login-form .login-button").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    check_login();
});
```

Remember to remove this:

`onSubmit="check_login();return false;`

Comment: Still reloading the page and sending GET headers.

Comment: Did you put that code inside `$(document).ready(function(){ })`?

Comment: Maybe you're having some cache issues with the web browser. Set a breakpoint with the chrome web inspector and check if the code is executing right. 

http://chromedevtools.googlecode.com/svn-history/r421/trunk/tutorials/breapoints/index.html

Answer (score 0):

The statement `check_login();return false` will not work. You have to call `return check_login();` and `return false` inside the function.

#### HTML

```
<form onsubmit="return check_login();">
   <!-- input fields here -->
</form>
```

#### Javascript

```
function check_login() {
    // Do your ajax call.
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Right way is:

**HTML Code:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    // Login function
    $(function() {
        $('.login-button').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'check-login.php',
                data: $('form.login-form').serialize(),
                success: function(response) {
                    if (response === '1') {
                        alert('Log In Success');
                    } else if (response === '2') {
                        alert('Incorrect Details');
                    } else if (response === '3') {
                        alert('Fill In All Fields');
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    })
    </script>
    <title>Ajax Login Form (Demo)</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form class="login-form" name="login-form" method="POST" action="">
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
        <button type="submit" class="btn trans login-button">Login</button>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

> **Write your ajax code inside**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//
}); or 

$(function(){
//
});
```

> **User Prevent Default to stop Form Submission**
>
> **You can use 'serialize' function to make POST pram.**

Answer (score 0):

there are a lot of way to do this:
write this code in your index:

`<a href="www.yourdomain.com" id="link_reload" style="display:none;">index</a>`

use "`eval`" function in javascript instead of "alert" to show the reasult
it means that on your PHP code when the code receive the true inputs and there is a user in your database like the input, the PHP code echo  javascript orders (bellow is your PHP codes that you send an ajax request to that):>

```
<?php if(response==1){
  echo '$("link_reload").trigger("click");';
} ?>
```

and in your javascript use evel() instead of alert()

Answer (score 0):

Remove the button type and use the onclick handler on it, not on the form.

It will also take care of the situation when it automatically submits on pressing enter key by accident.

Happy Coding !!!

Comment: You can use it via Jquery also, but for a single action its better to use onclick. On th eother hand if you have multiple actions of a single click you should use Jquery.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the input type from "submit" to a regular button whose onclick action is to call check_login()